# Exchanging strings between TeX and Lua

Tags: errors, luatex, lua

I have a multi-language CV written in LuaLaTeX. To switch between the different languages I am using two Lua functions that are called through these TeX commands:

```
\directlua{code = require("code")}

\newcommand{\lc}[1]{\directlua{code.sel_lang(#1)}}
\newcommand{\setlang}{\directlua{code.set_lang()}}

\begin{document}

\setlang{}

\lc{{
  eng="Ravenna, Italy",
  ita="Ravenna, Italia",
  swe="Ravenna, Italien"
}}
\lc{{
  eng="B.Sc.\\ in Computer Science",
  ita="Laurea triennale in Scienze Informatiche",
  swe="Kandidatexamen i datavetenskap"
}}
```

The Lua code is the following:

```lua
-- Language Table
local languages = {}
languages["eng"] = "english"
languages["ita"] = "italian"
languages["swe"] = "swedish"

-- Main Language
local main_language = "english"

-- Language defined in the jobname cmd parameter
local cmd_language = string.sub(tex.jobname, -3)
texio.write_nl("Command line language: "..cmd_language)
local language = languages[cmd_language]

-- Set language for TeX directives
function set_document_language()
    texio.write_nl("Setting babel language")
    tex.sprint("\\selectlanguage{"..language.."}")
end

-- Print text in the desired language
function select_language(langmap)
    if (langmap[cmd_language] == nil) then
        tex.sprint("!! Missing Text !!")
    end
    tex.sprint(langmap[cmd_language])
end

return { sel_lang = select_language, set_lang = set_document_language }
```

This used to work with an older version of LuaLaTeX but now the "`\\`" after B.Sc. trigger the following error:

```
[\directlua]:1: invalid escape sequence near '"B.Sc.\A'.
\lc #1->\directlua {code.sel_lang(#1)}
```

#### Attempt to fix the error

To fix the error I have tried to pass the Lua function an escaped string instead:

```
\newcommand{\lc}[1]{\directlua{code.sel_lang("\luaescapestring{\unexpanded{#1}}")}}
```

and I have modified the Lua function as follows:

```lua
-- Print text in the desired language
function select_language(langmap)
    texio.write_nl("String received:" ..langmap) --debug
    string = load("return "..langmap)()
    if (langmap[cmd_language] == nil) then
        tex.sprint("!! Missing Text !!")
    end
    tex.sprint(langmap[cmd_language])
end
```

but now I get errors like the following one:

```
String received:{ eng="ABOUT ME", ita="PRESENTAZIONE", swe="OM MIG" }...exmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-auxiliary.lua:970: attempt to call a nil value (field 'lower').
```

where Lua is trying to call non-existent functions on the table structure.

Can you give me an idea on how to proceed/what to try?

I hope the issue is understandable and I apologize for any mistake and unclear explanation, I am not an expert in either Tex or Lua.

Thank you very much!

Comment: `\string\\ `  I guess

Comment: Are you familiar with the [luacode](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/luacode) package? It provides a macro that may be of interest to you: `\luastringN`, which passes its argument *unexpanded* to Lua. It would allow the following, simpler definition of `\lc`: `\newcommand{\lc}[1]{\directlua{ code.sel_lang(\luastringN{#1})}}`.

Comment: Just curiosity. Why are you using lua to switch the language?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I tried that but it did not work, unfortunately I do not recall the exact error I got.

Comment: @Mico Thank you very much! It was exactly what I needed! If you post it as an answer I will gladly accept it :)

Comment: @JavierBezos It is because I very much prefer to work with Lua rather than LaTeX. I have really tried to learn LaTeX but it is so different from every other programming language that I can not really wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [luacode](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/luacode) package is probably best known for providing the `luacode` and `luacode*` environments. However, that's not all this package has to offer. In particular, it also provides three LaTeX macros for passing string variables from TeX to Lua. They are

- `\luastring`  -- fully expands its argument
- `\luastringN` -- does *not* expand its argument
- `\luastringO` -- expands its argument exactly *once*

Importantly, the arguments of these macros are always treated as strings. E.g., `\luastring{1}` passes `1` as a *string* rather than as an *integer* to Lua.

Using `\luastringN`, you could simplify

```
\newcommand{\lc}[1]{\directlua{code.sel_lang("\luaescapestring{\unexpanded{#1}}")}
```

to

```
\newcommand{\lc}[1]{\directlua{code.sel_lang(\luastringN{#1})}}
```